# How do I start the cron daemon automatically on Raspbmc?

Tags: raspbmc, cron

I'm not able to start the cron daemon automatically on Raspbmc. I tried to configure an upstart and an init script but had no luck.

Comment: Are you using an older release candidate of RaspBMC?  I had similar problems getting samba to start on boot and it turned out to be descrepancies between the release candidate I was using and the incremental updates which had been applied.  I ended up having to rebuild my sd card from the latest build to get it sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under raspbmc settings, activate Cronjob scheduler

Answer (score 0):

You can set it via the settings as per user9428's answer, and also activate by setting the following to *true*:

```
<setting id="sys.service.cron" value="true" />
```

in the following file:

```
/home/pi/.xbmc/userdata/addon_data/script.raspbmc.settings/settings.xml
```

Replace .xbmc with .kodi if you're on Kodi already.